# shell executing number of commands

Tags: ruby

I need to execute a set of commands like this:

```
system("command1; command2; command3")
```

is there any advantage in terms of speed or any other metrics if I do it like above instead of doing

```
system "command1"
system "command2"
system "command3"
```

Comment: Why don’t you benchmark it and find out?

Comment: Are you *sure* these shell commands need a `system` call? It is quite unusual to find something that native Ruby can't do - especially three things at once - and it is certainly something you should consider if speed is important to you. Would you consider sharing with us what these commands are?

Comment: I am creating a mysql backup using `mysqldump`. I need to dump several tables, using `where` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, Ruby execution is slower than shell script, so expanding the sequence into three commands within shell is faster than doing it in Ruby.

But the speed difference is probably small. And what matters more is whether each of the three commands have a logical significance within the Ruby code. If they are to be considered one chunk that is never separated within the level of logic in the Ruby code, then it makes more sense to connect them in shell. If each command does correspond to some logical concept in the Ruby code, then it makes more sense to separate them.

Benchmark

```
t = Time.now
100.times do
  system("echo foo; ls; echo bar ")
end
t1 = Time.now - t

t = Time.now
100.times do
  system("echo foo ")
  system("ls ")
  system("echo bar ")
end
t2 = Time.now - t

puts "Together: #{t1}", "Separate: #{t2}"
```

Result

```
Together: 0.673181442
Separate: 1.177105366
```

Comment: “Ruby execution is slower than shell script” do you have any actual proof of that? Most of Ruby’s “slowness” for running a trivial script is in the VM startup and require phase, which has already happened at this point.

Comment: Nice. Though I doubt it’s really Ruby that’s slow and more so the overhead of spawning three shell processes instead of just one.

Comment: You are right. I think most of the time is spent on Ruby calling shell and responding to the result, which are Ruby processes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @sawa's answer there is [spawn](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn), which does not wait for the process to end before starting the next process. It's faster:

```
n = 100
t = Time.now
n.times do
  system("echo foo; ls; echo bar ")
end
t1 = Time.now - t

t = Time.now
n.times do
  system("echo foo ")
  system("ls ")
  system("echo bar ")
end
t2 = Time.now - t

t = Time.now
n.times do
  spawn("echo foo ")
  spawn("ls ")
  spawn("echo bar ")
end
t3 = Time.now - t

t = Time.now
n.times do
  spawn("echo foo; ls; echo bar ")
end
t4 = Time.now - t

puts "Together: #{t1}", "Separate: #{t2}", "Spawned: #{t3}",, "Spawned together: #{t4}"
```

Output:

```
Together: 0.242906748
Separate: 0.379665418
Spawned: 0.1551359
Spawned together: 0.083032541
```